# My menu links are not working on wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

This function is working on php site but when I convert it to wordpress my menu links are not working and is adding another url. Here is an example of my url after I click one of my menu links: http://localhost/wordpress/#http://localhost/wordpress/

```
$(document).on("click", "#footer .menu a, .logo a", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");

    window.location.hash = url.replace(".php", "");

    if(!$(this).hasClass("no-ajax") && !$(this).hasClass("active")) {

        $("#footer .menu a, .logo a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#site-loader").fadeIn("medium", function() {

        $("#main-content #main-content-load").fadeOut("medium", function() {

                $("#main-content").addClass("transitioning");

                $("#main-content").load(url + " #main-content-load", function() {

                    $("#main-content #main-content-load").fadeIn("medium", function() {

                        if(url == "index.php") {
                            initSlider();
                        }

                        if(url == "about-us.php") {
                            initAboutSlider();
                        }

                        $("#main-content").removeClass("transitioning");
                        $("#site-loader").fadeOut("medium");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }

    $("#footer").removeClass("expanded");
});
```

Comment: How can someone access your provided localhost url?

Comment: what is in your href tag from which you are getting the URL.? add your HTML also.

Comment: You can't because i am working without web hosting but i provided it just as an example of what is happening with my url after i click one of my menu links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines are making that URL

```
var url = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
window.location.hash = url.replace(".php", "");
```

What you are doing is adding a hashed location to to the current url, i.e., you are redirecting `http://localhost/wordpress/` to the anchor `#http://localhost/wordpress/`

If you are just trying to get the end file, you'll have to split apart url, perhaps:

```
var urlParts = url.replace(".php", "").split('/');
window.location.hash = urlParts[urlParts.length-1];
```